# sql server 2008 cursor implementation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-cursor

I would like to know how cursor actually works in sql server 2008. For example, are the results held in memory as soon as the cursor is opened? or the results stored in an intermediate format, the real data is retrieved when fetch?

Comment: Best book on SQL Internals is "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals" IMO. It doesn't cover cursors though. Chapter 14 of "SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled" has a good overview of cursors. The implementation depends. There are different permutations. (Client-Side/Server-Side and Forward Only/Static/Keyset/Dynamic) Static cursors will create a snapshot of results in tempdb when the cursor is opened. Dynamic operate directly on base tables.